# Is there a way to sign a 624 bits message on 256 bits

Tags: digital-signature

I'm looking for a way to sign a 624 bits message on 256bits (sig length = 256 bits) with an asymmetric keys system?

I'm trying to sign a qrcode so a client can be sure that this qrcode has been emitted by the server.

It should be very hard to generate a qr code without the private key. (It should take more than a month)

The client has a public key.

Is it possible to obtain a "secure" (Meaning I can't sign my own qr code under a month without knowing the private key) priv/pub key signature system on such a restricted space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; [BLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh-Lynn-Shacham) can do that.  (Message length is only relevant to short signatures in very limited circumstances.)